# State machine using SOLID principles. Connecting to real devices

Tags: c#, design-patterns, solid, state

I am trying to implement code for switching states of a couple laboratory devices. **My considerations are: how should I link the state objects, state machine object and device manager object to follow SOLID prinziples. Should StateMachineContext know about DeviceManager object? - explanation and code are below.**  I will be very grateful for any hints how could I implement it better. Please also leave a comments if this aproach is the right one or if you had more sutable one for such task.

**Problem description:**

Code should switch states of a couple laboratory devices. Besides switching states of devices some steps should do actions independent of real devices - e.g. send data(current time, operator name etc. - data unrelated to devices). The architecture should follow SOLID principles. Below I have placed my code.

The main parts of my implementation are StateMachineConext, States, DeviceManager. To get know States about configured devices one possibility would be to pass DeviceManager object containig list of configured devices to StateMachineConext. Steps would then get passed the StateMachineContext. I don't like this idea because, there are also some steps just for sending the data unrelated to devices. Another possiblity could be to implement a StepProvider - some kind of factory class which would pass DeviceManager object only to device related state objects like Initialize, Start, Stop. However I don't really like this idea too.

The simplified workflow would be:

1. Standby
2. Initiate
3. Run messurement
4. Send data(this step has nothing to do with configured devices)
5. Stop devices
6. Standby

Following GoF state pattern and some other examples I have implemented following classes:

```
public class StateMachineContext
{
    private StateBase currentState;       

    public StateBase CurrentState
    {
        get
        {
            return currentState;
        }

        set
        {
            currentState = value;
        }
    }

    public void ActivateNextState()
    {
        currentState.ActivateNextState();            
    }

    public void ExecuteState()
    {
        currentState.Execute();
    }
}

public class StateStandby : StateBase
{
    public StateStandby(StateMachineContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override void ActivateNextState()
    {
        this.context.CurrentState = new StateInitialize(base.context);
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        CurrentAction = "Standby...";
    }
}

public class StateInitialize : StateBase
{
    public StateInitialize(StateMachineContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override void ActivateNextStep()
    {
         this.context.CurrentState = new StateCheckDeviceReadyness(base.context);
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        CurrentAction = "Initializing devices...";
        //this.context.DeviceManager.PreapareDevicesToReadState(); - I don't like this. Why StateMachineContext should know about devices? What could be a the better solution?
    }
}

public class StateRunMessurement : StateBase
{
    public StateRunMessurement (StateMachineContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override void ActivateNextStep()
    {
         this.context.CurrentState = new StateSendData(base.context);
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        CurrentAction = "Running mesurement on each device...";
        //this.context.DeviceManager.RunDevices(); - I don't like this. Why StateMachineContext should know about devices? What could be a the better solution?
    }
}

public class DeviceManager : IDeviceManager
{
    private List<IDevice> configuredDevices = new List<IDevice>();

    public DeviceManager()
    {
        configuredDevices.Add(new Pump());
        configuredDevices.Add(new Oven());
    }

    public void PreapareDevicesToReadState()
    {
        foreach (IDevice device in configuredDevices)
        {
            device.GetReady();
        }
    }

    public void RunDevices()
    {
        foreach (IDevice device in configuredDevices)
        {
            device.Run();
        }
    }

    public void StopDevices()
    {
        foreach (IDevice device in configuredDevices)
        {
            device.Stop();
        }
    }
}

public partial class FormStateMachine : Form
{
    StateMachineContext stateMachineContext = new StateMachineContext();

    public FormStateMachine()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        stateMachineContext.CurrentStep = new StateStandby(stateMachineContext);
    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stateMachineContext.ActivateNextState();
        stateMachineContext.ExecuteState();
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see a state machine. A state machine manages state transfers, some of which would be conditional. This is no such thing, you just have a fixed sequence of events with a beginning and an end that may either make it all the way to the end or not.

Comment: @Martin Maat Maat thank you very much for your comment. Good point! I am aware of transitions, but somehow I thought that the simplest state mache will have the "fixed" states. According to wikipedia there should be defined transitions and input params for changing the state. My fault - I falsely called my classes and the post description. However, the main problem for me is still the same. How should I pass the DeviceManager object to State objects? Should the StateMachineContext store the DeviceManager object or should there be another object which provides DeviceManager object to states?

Comment: In addition to my previous comment: State pattern is close to state machine.  From Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine The following concepts are commonly used to build software applications with finite-state machines: Automata-based programming, Event-driven finite-state machine, Virtual finite-state machine, State design pattern.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern says: "This pattern is close to the concept of finite-state machines". It would be great if someone could give me hints for my origin questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are still missing the point.

A device would not need to know about its manager. The manager would create some devices and put them to work when it is time to do so. Devices can be just slaves unaware of whom or what tells them what to do.

The only state your devices can have is "Idle" so there is no point using a state machine or anything focussed on state. Measuring is not really a state, it is not stable, it will automatically go back to idle once the measurement is done and the results have been sent. You just have one method `Device.ProduceMeasurementResult()` that can be called.

It is not like a train ticket dispenser that can output a ticket but only after a user put some money in it and told the machine where he wants to go. To get to the result, multiple states need to be visited, all triggered by the external party (the user), in the right order. This is a complex process with multiple checkpoints that may either direct the state forward or back (one step or all the way to the beginning) if a condition is not met. You have none of that. Your process is linear and one-way only, which is why there is no sensible answer to your question.

And SOLID has nothing to do with state machines.

> If the only tool you've got is a hammer, every problem just has to be
> a nail.

It is like you have that hammer and the task to dig a hole in the ground. Then you ponder "I was thinking of banging a grid pattern of dents in the soil... Any ideas on improving on that? Should I use the other side of the hammer maybe?"

And people just stare for a moment and walk by. You either need a better (more straightforward) approach or a better problem that fits your solution.

Comment: Once again thanks @Martin Maat for taking time on my post. I try to clear my thoughts what and how I want to implement. Unfortunatelly it is not easy to find complete and useful examples which are: 1. clearly programmed and 2. doing somethig real with hardware(most of them has inside methods comments like - "this state should switch lamp/change color/open door...", but they do nothing real). I will edit and correct my origin post I'll try to explain what I have learned so far.